# Saber a direção entre pontos através de coordenada latitude e longitude com php

Tags: php

Galera seguinte tenho 3 cidades que vamos chama de ponto  (A) (B) (C)  todas com latitude e longitude a topologia de fica mais ou menos assim:

```
A = -3.3105, -60.1694

B = -3.3242, -60.6281

C = -3.5970, -61.3930
```

> Direções (A) <--Barco Viajando--> (B) <--Barco Viajando--> (C)

Obs: Entre o ponto A ao C tenho tenho um barco viajando, e tenho latitude e longitude "coordenada" a cada 2 minutos desse barco:

Agora vem questão que eu quero saber, se tem como saber se ele esta indo do ponto para qual ponto tipo assim:

```
(A) --> (B)

(C) --> (B) 

(B) --> (A)
```

Espero tenham me entendido peço que se alguem pode me ajudar agradeço muito mesmo !

Comment: Qual é a fórmula para esse cálculo ? Porque para "separar os valores" e ver a diferença, é só usar um `explode`, assim separa LA de LO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Update 2]

Script final (ainda pode ser melhorado):

```
// Detalhes
$n_pontoA = "Iranduba"; // Nome do ponto A
$n_pontoB = "Manaus";   // Nome do ponto B

// Coordenadas
$c1_barco = '-3.3105, -60.1694'; // Posição anterior do barco
$c2_barco = '-3.3137, -60.3477'; // Posição atual do barco
$c_pontoA = '-3.3242, -60.6281'; // Ponto A
$c_pontoB = '-3.5970, -61.3930'; // Ponto B

function quebra($coordenadas) {

    // Separa os valores
    $v = explode(",",$coordenadas);

    return $v;
}

// https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}

function calcula($c1Barco, $c2Barco, $cPontoA, $cPontoB) {

    // Quebra Latitude de Longitude
    $barcoC1 = quebra($c1Barco);
    $barcoC2 = quebra($c2Barco);
    $pontoA = quebra($cPontoA);
    $pontoB = quebra($cPontoB);

    // Calcula a distância entre os pontos
    $db1a = round(distance($barcoC1[0],$barcoC1[1],$pontoA[0],$pontoA[1],"K"),2);
    $db1b = round(distance($barcoC1[0],$barcoC1[1],$pontoB[0],$pontoB[1],"K"),2);
    $db2a = round(distance($barcoC2[0],$barcoC2[1],$pontoA[0],$pontoA[1],"K"),2);
    $db2b = round(distance($barcoC2[0],$barcoC2[1],$pontoB[0],$pontoB[1],"K"),2);

    // Tira a diferença da posição barco x pontos
    $dPA = $db1a - $db2a;
    $dPB = $db1b - $db2b;

    // Verifica a maior distância percorrida
    if ($dPA > $dPB)
        return "A";
    else
        return "B";
}

// Executa a função passando as variáveis
$resultado = calcula($c1_barco, $c2_barco, $c_pontoA, $c_pontoB);

if ($resultado == "A")
    echo "Destino: " . $n_pontoA;
else if ($resultado == "B")
    echo "Destino: " . $n_pontoB;
else
    echo "Erro!";
```

---

#### [Resposta 1]

Primeiro você precisa ter bem definida a fórmula da distância, pois elas podem conter valores positivos e/ou negativos, mas poderá resolver de forma simples.

*Se irá calcular "velocidade média", é um pouco mais complexo do que parece, pois como terá 3 pontos, ao invés de 1, teria que fazer o cálculo separadamente.*

Feito isso, você quebra os 2 valores, faz os cálculos conforme sua definição, e depois simplesmente faz a diferença entre eles.

Exemplo das funções:

```
// Coordenadas
$A = '-3.3105, -60.1694';
$B = '-3.3242, -60.6281';
$C = '-3.5970, -61.3930';

function distancia($ponto1, $ponto2) {

    // Separa os valores
    $p1 = explode(",",$ponto1);
    $p2 = explode(",",$ponto2);

    // Calcula a diferença
    $dLA = $p1[0] - $p2[0];
    $dLO = $p1[1] - $p2[1];

    echo '<br> LA: ' . $dLA . ' | LO: ' . $dLO;
}

distancia($A,$B);
distancia($B,$A);
distancia($A,$C);
```

Resultado:

```
LA: 0.0137 | LO: 0.4587
LA: -0.0137 | LO: -0.4587
LA: 0.2865 | LO: 1.2236
```

Função separando cada coordenada para trabalhar com elas fora de uma função:

```
function distancia2($ponto1, $ponto2) {

    // Separa os valores
    $p1 = explode(",",$ponto1);
    $p2 = explode(",",$ponto2);

    // Calcula a diferença
    $d["LA"] = $p1[0] - $p2[0];
    $d["LO"] = $p1[1] - $p2[1];

    return $d;
}

$dA_B = distancia2($A,$B);
$dB_C = distancia2($B,$C);
$dA_C = distancia2($A,$C);

echo '<br>' . $dA_B["LA"];
echo '<br>' . $dB_C["LA"];
echo '<br>' . $dA_C["LA"];
echo '<br>' . $dA_B["LO"];
echo '<br>' . $dB_C["LO"];
echo '<br>' . $dA_C["LO"];
```

Comment: Mas você tendo as coordenadas e fazendo a diferença entre elas, você terá a posição do barco. Com essa 2a função, é só jogar na fórmula dele.

Comment: Diretor da uma olhada ai nessa url http://grupoleopardo.com/app/kibarco/expresso-crystal-i/

Comment: @GrupoLeopardo Muito bacana ! A parte de "velocidade" já é algo mais delicado. Vou postar na resposta

Comment: Aqui na frente que eu queria colocar na frente para onde esta indo http://grupoleopardo.com/app/kibarco

Comment: a parte da velocidade ja esta ok

Comment: tem como agente falar pelo chat pode ser?

Comment: Essa aplicação já é sua então ? Achei que estava começando, e queria reproduzi-la. Mas então, você precisa ter sua fórmula para poder aplicar no script. Vamos supor que você hoje iria calcular na mão, no papel e caneta. Como você faria para calcular isso ? Tendo isso em mãos, já facilitaria demais o que você precisa. Em vista você terá 6 variáveis de posição (3 LA e 3 LO), e 6 de distância (3 distâncias calculadas, 3 distâncias anteriores).

Comment: Sim, só não sei como criar chat ! rs

Comment: Tenho pouca reputação ainda começando agora mais aqui abaixo apareceu pra mim mais não posso iniciar devido minha reputação ser baixa ainda eu acho rsrsss tenta ai

Comment: Tem um problema sério aí: vocês estão calculando como se o planeta fosse plano. Sugiro estudarem geodésicas

Comment: @Bacco eu ia falar sobre isso, pois uma vez estava vendo sobre APP com GPS, e sorte que o Android tem classe pronta para isso, já considerando a curvatura da terra. Isso vale para velocidade correto !?

Comment: @Bacco seguinte: tenho no banco todos as coordenada do barco data e hora a cada 2 min isso no caso me ajuda a chegar onde quero ?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77036/roomw1d1d1wr4yw46u2